# How do you call tasks in gulp with live reload - after file changes have occured

Tags: gulp, livereload

I defined in a gulp file, the following task:

```
gulp.task('watch:livereload', function(){
  livereload.listen();
  gulp.watch('app/**').on('change', livereload.changed);
});
```

Which only recently did I realize is great only for static things like html. Because I use sass and the app is primarily js. I would like to call some tasks I have predefined to recompile the js and css upon any change to them.

The way I have been calling tasks is by:

```
gulp.task('compile:development',
  [
    'bower',
    'compile:scripts:development',
    'compile:sass:development',
    'serve',
    'watch:livereload'
  ]
);
```

But I want the tasks to happen on change. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep using `livereload` just as you do, for browser refresh purposes. If you want to re-run some tasks upon change, I think that `gulp.watch` is the simple and built-in way to go.

```
gulp.watch('app/**', ['compile:development']);
```

Or more specific tasks :

```
gulp.watch('app/**', ['compile:scripts:development', 'compile:sass:development']);
```

Example of a `watch` task which defines some `watchers` with different `tasks` :

```
gulp.task('watch', function () {
   gulp.watch('app/sass/*', ['compile:sass:development']);
   gulp.watch('app/js/*', ['compile:scripts:development']);
});
```

Comment: Would this be a separate task or can I build it off my existing one?

Comment: Personally I would advice you to create a `watch` task that will contain all your different `watchers`, so you can find them easily

Comment: Can you update your answer to show an example of how one might do this? (please)

Comment: Of course, just done that based on your tasks and imaginary paths